# と　particle after a full sentence

Tags: particle-と

In my book I have this sentence:

> 生徒が学校へ行こうと思って野を歩いていると、一ぴきのきつねが遠くにいるのをみた。

I understand the sentence, "The student, who is walking in the field while he wants to go to school, saw a fox far away".

But what's the purpose of "と" here?

Comment: Are you sure your textbook says `生徒が学校へ行こうと思って野を歩いていると、一ぴきのきつねが遠くにいるのをみた`, not 「生徒が学校へ行こうと思って野を歩いていると、一匹のきつねが遠くにいるの**が見えた** 」 or 「～～、一匹のきつねが遠くに**見えた** 」?

Comment: See also: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/393/9831・https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24463/9831・https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17416/9831

Answer (score 0):

と in this case implies that something **unexpected** is following.
"The student was walking in the field to go to school, when he saw a fox far away."
Or we can emphasize like that to see the nuance:
"Just when the student thought of going to school and was walking in the field, he saw a fox far away."